# The media could not be loaded error when trying to play a video in videojs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video.js

I am using videojs in my React project. I am trying to play a video from the local path. But I am getting an error when I am trying to do so. Here is my path I am giving to the video source and I am attaching the project structure also.

```
 <video id="myvideo" src="./src/pages/VideoScreen/CarChase.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

here is my project structure

[image: Project Structure]

Here is my error

[image]

Also why my .mp4 files are in red. Is there anything wrong?

I added these loader in my webpack also to try

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=video:src'
}, {
    test: /\.mp4$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4'
},
```

But this also didn't work. Am I giving the path in a wrong way?

Comment: Are the video files generated on the WebPack output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url loader doesn't work with `src` attributes inside jsx. You have to import your video file like that :

```
import videoSrc from './src/pages/VideoScreen/CarChase.mp4';

//...

id="myvideo"
src={videoSrc}
type="video/mp4"
```

Comment: So do it need to put these loader (the one I mentioned in ques) and change the code as u suggested in ur answer?

Comment: Yes, you have to set the configuration `{ test: /\.mp4$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4' }` to make it work

Comment: and what if I want to make a request to a server and then the server returns a string url of requested video. Now then I ll have to pass the returned string only in the src. Will it work in that case?

Comment: No, it will only works for files that will be found on app build time (like in your screen capture). For external urls, you just have fill the `src` attribute of your video.